# writing a matrix into a txt file with ; after each row C++?

Tags: c++, file-io, matrix

I have a matrix " PowerMatrix" which is of size 24 * 24 now i need to know how can i write this matrix into a text file with a ; after each row? how can i do this? 
i have this code up till now but it's not working i don't know why and yet i can't separate using a ; after each row?

```
std::ofstream output("Power vector.txt"); 
for (k=1; k<PowerMatrix.size(); k++)
{
for (l=1; l<PowerMatrix.size(); l++)
{
output << PowerMatrix[i][j] << " "; // behaves like cout - cout is also a stream
}
output << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `;` before the newline:

```
std::ofstream output("Power vector.txt"); 
for (k=1; k<PowerMatrix.size(); k++)
{
    for (l=1; l<PowerMatrix.size(); l++)
    {
        output << PowerMatrix[i][j] << " "; // behaves like cout - cout is also a stream
    }
    output << ";" << endl;
}
```